# React component library - (plugin rpt2) RollupError: Expected 'from' got 'typeof'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, build, rollupjs

I'm creating a library using TypeScript and React, and I want the library to contain both React and React Native components.  When I do `npm run build` with no Native code, it compiles fine. However, when I try to add in Native components and then run `npm run build`, I get this error:

```
(plugin rpt2) RollupError: Expected 'from', got 'typeof' in /Users/XXXXX/node_modules/react-native/index.js
12: 
13: // Components
14: import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
```

My stack is React, TypeScript, rollup, and babel.

Here's my rollup.config.js:

```
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete';
import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'esm',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    del({ targets: 'dist/*' }),
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.build.json',
      useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true,
    }),
    postcss(),
  ],
};
```

All of my components are just `tsx` files that I export like this in the entrypoint index.ts:

```
export { default as Footer } from './components/Footer';
export { default as Header } from './components/Header';
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks